# How to explain oversampling replacing with extremely good-to-perfect results?

Tags: machine-learning, resampling, precision-recall

I have extremely imbalanced data (100:1) where the 1 part is my interested (minority) class. I have heard about the oversampling (among other techniques) to be a way to "handle" imbalanced data. So what I did is to oversample the minority class by resampling with replacement to a certain ratio (say, 2:1).

I then split this newly formed (re)sample into training and testing set, and the performance vastly increased from precision, recall, F1 of 0.7, 0.4, 0.5 to 0.97, 0.97, 0.97.

Am I doing anything wrong since it seems too good to be true? Should I retain the original distribution for the testing set, and only oversample the minority class in my training set instead?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the way you're building your sets, then it's very likely that almost all of the "interesting" points in your test set are also in the training set. Your model is probably overfitting, and learning to regurgitate the training data exactly without necessarily generalizing, and you have no way to detect it because you're not validating the model using data from outside the training set. Separating the data into training and testing before applying oversampling should prevent this.